# Rolling Release Dual Boot

Tags: linux, dual-boot, rolling-release

Right now I am using Ubuntu GNOME and Windows 8 dual boot on the same hard drive. But my Gnome desktop is laggy and I do not like it very much. Because of that, I am thinking about switching to a KDE desktop. 
I searched a bit and I found Chakra, and I like it very much. The problem is that it is a rolling release, which means it is not as stable as a LTS version. Could that be a problem for dual boot?

I assume the risks of using one, but I don't want to also damage my windows install if something breaks. Is it even possible for that to happen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not really, no. While LTS releases are indeed more stable, that does not mean that rolling releases are inherently *unstable*. It just means that they might have updates that break something more often. It will still be rare though.

More importantly, it is very hard for a problem in Linux to affect your Windows install. Yes, it is possible, but no, it is no more likely with a rolling release than with an LTR one. To affect your Windows install your Linux will have to somehow write to the Windows partition and there is no reason why it should. The systems are completely separate and, unless you do something like format the Windows drive by mistake, they will remain so.

Another point worth making is that there is absolutely no reason to change distributions if you just want to change your desktop environment (DE). You can install KDE on your current OS, no need to change OSs just to get a facelift!

While in recent years DEs have gotten more complex and intrusive, you can still switch between them. On Ubuntu, just run

```
sudo apt-get install kde-desktop
```

You might loose some branding, your system will suddenly believe it is Kubuntu but there shouldn't be any serious issues. The worst that might happen is that a few applications won't look quite right. For example, I have Cinnamon and XFCE4 installed on my machine and they can coexist quite happily.

The bottom line is 1) no, a rolling distribution is no danger to your Windows and 2) changing OS to change desktop environments is like buying a new car because you need to change your headlights.

Comment: I think a rolling release might be a little more problematic if you are not updating it regularly.

Comment: @strongbad why? If you don't update regularly, you are open to security issues that were recently patched but your system also remains as stable as it was. Why would a rolling release be different? In any case, the OP said nothing about updates and whether you update or not, your Windows install should remain unaffected.

Comment: Arch [recommends upgrading regularly](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/System_maintenance#Regularly_upgrade_the_system) to avoid having to handle lots of manual interventions. I was focused on the first question about drawbacks of a rolling release with dual boots, not the breaking windows part.

Comment: The thing is that the Gnome desktop right now is really laggy. For example I can't even use the terminal with vim without lag. And I already tried a lot of different terminals. That was the reason I was thinking about switching distros (of course is not just vim, browser and file manager also)

Comment: But I will give it a try with installing kde in my current distro. If the problem persists I will switch to another one.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to go with a triple boot system and have grub setup from a minimal **stable**  installation. It would be bad enough if the rolling release could not be booted, but at least that way you can always access your Windows installation.

Something like 10Gb should be more than enough for such an installation, but you can further minimze that (not sure how much effort you should put into that with today's disk sizes).

The only problem is that an update of the kernel of Chakra doesn't normally show up until you boot the stable linux and run `update-grub`. You can of course have Chakra insert new values in the stable installations `/boot/grub/grub.cfg` if that is a problem.

Comment: But if I had dual boot and couldn't boot on my linux distro, wouldn't I be able to boot on windows? I didn't really understand the triple boot part.

Comment: You would be able to boot the stable linux and windows (using grub via the stable linux). The third linux would be Chakra and could completely break without affecting booting the other two.

Comment: Oh I understand. Do you use chakra? Is it stable enough? Maybe I should just go with linux mint or something for maximum stability.

Comment: No, I don't use chakra, but I do have a triple boot system. I'm not sure Windows still boots, it's been so long and I normally experiment by using Virtual Machines, but that would not help in your case.